# How to set custom auto Login for custom Registration form in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This is user Registration custom form in laravel.

```
public function register(RegisterTalentRequest $request) 
{
    $talent = $this->create($request->except('_method', '_token'));

    //up till here the registration values are successfully saved in the 
    //database table, but it's not logged in following the below code
    //and is directing to the custom login page.

    Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password]);

    return redirect()->route('dashboard'); //directing to login and not dashboard
}
```

Comment: have you hashed your password before storing into the database?

Comment: Are you using multiple guards?

Comment: Yes, @Moshiur I've used Hash.

Comment: Yes, @Rwd I'm using multiple guards.

Comment: Is the guard for this meant to be different to your default guard for this login?

Comment: Yes, @Rwd. They are different.

Comment: What is the guard called? Please can you also show the routes you have for this method and any middleware it's under?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `Auth` facade (or `auth()` helper function), you will be using the default `guard` set up in your `config/auth.php` file.

If you're wanting to use a different guard inside a login or register method you need to explicitly set it:

```
Auth::guard('guard-name')->attempt(...);
```

**Alternatively**, when using the `auth` or `guest` middleware, you can pass the guard you're wanting to use e.g. (`auth:guard-name` or `guest:guard-name`) this will then set the default guard to be `guard-name` for the rest of the request so you don't need to explicitly set it.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that in you registration it returned a user. then you can use this

```
Auth::login($user);
```

Comment: Please can you explain your answer.

Comment: I'm assuming that inside your registration you inserted a new user right ? Then you can find the id for that user and use these codes
$user = User::find($user_id) and set this user logged in by using Auth::login($user)

Comment: or you can use this one, just provide the exact guard.
Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])

Comment: Since its the custom user, I've tried adding the custom variable $talent instead of $user. But it's not working and is redirecting me to the same url i.e. login page.

Comment: Sorry, I meant please could you add the explanation to your answer. That way if other people come along they have an idea as to why this would help :)

Comment: so variable $talent is a newly user registered ?